# How to disable push button - Win32 API

Tags: c++, winapi

I creating a program, i need : after click Button A, do something, and disable button A (mean that button is selected, not to be continue clicked !)

I see MSDN this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb849162%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

but I don't known using this (I also use it as function but : error: Button_Enable not identified)

Comment: Did you include `windowsx.h`, like the link says?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that macro, but [EnableWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646291%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) should work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To use Button_Enable macro, You need to insert

```
#include <windowsx.h>
```

in your header file.

Or, you can use `EnableWindow()` function:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646291%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 13):

Or you can use code like this
    ::EnableWindow(hBtn,false)

Answer (score 4):

Or you can use EnableWindow with getting window handle if your dialog box that contains the control which need to disable:

```
EnableWindow(GetDlgItem(hwndDlg,BTN_TRIM),false); // to disable button or other control
EnableWindow(GetDlgItem(hwndDlg,BTN_TRIM),true);  // to enable button or other control
```

`hwndDlg` - A handle to the dialog box that contains the control
`BTN_TRIM` - The identifier of the control to be retrieved